# Can I have more than one database per gear in openshift?

Tags: mysql, openshift

I've deployed Java apps and now a Grails app connected in OpenShift ... so far so good (cool service)

I can deploy more than 1 app to a single gear... but **can I have more than 1 DB per gear ?**

This config is making me think I can't

```
  String host = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')
  String port = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')
  String dbName = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME')
  url = "jdbc:mysql://$host:$port/$dbName"
  username = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME')
  password = System.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')
```

took from this post:
[Configuring DataSource.groovy for Openshift for Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352276/configuring-datasource-groovy-for-openshift-for-grails)

If I couldn't have more than DB per gear would suck ...

**So can I have more than 1 DB per gear ?**

Comment: Are you sure its possible to deply more than 1 app per gear?

Comment: This was back in 2014 but yeah it was possible and I think it should still be possible as it doesn't make any sense to be forced to have a gear per application.

Comment: If you're still using openShift could you check just to make sure? I can't seem to find how perhaps they changed it, although I agree it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not using OpenShift anymore, I'm more focused on FE development at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would having just another database created on the gear suffice? or do you want 2 separate mysql processes running?

If you want two separate databases you could just ssh into your gear, use mysql to create another database. Then just create a custom environment variable to reference that second DB. ie. you could use $OPENSHIFT_APP_DB2 and use the same host and port details to connect.

If you need help getting custom environment variables you could use [this](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1072-how-to-create-and-use-environment-variables-on-the-server) for reference.

Comment: Another DB in the same gear is enough...sounds very promising. ..let me try it